# Cannot install Facebook SDK 3.5.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, macos, installation

I know I can build it from sources, but it looks like a pkg bug or something.

Basically, I open the package in the Installer.app, click `Continue` and `Install` and... nothing happens.

Here are the complete installer logs:

```
Installer[43732]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-735
Installer[43732]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-614
Installer[43732]: Hardware: iMac12,2 @ 3.40 GHz (x 8), 16384 MB RAM
Installer[43732]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Installer[43732]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Installer[43732]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/gs/z_zjkd5500v67p65k5ttbs7h0000gn/T/
Installer[43732]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Installer[43732]: Env: HOME=/Volumes/DataHD/myusername
Installer[43732]: Env: USER=myusername
Installer[43732]: Env: LOGNAME=myusername
Installer[43732]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-dBvC0f/Listeners
Installer[43732]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-CJLhSk/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
Installer[43732]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-qscn6h/Render
Installer[43732]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Installer[43732]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Installer[43732]: Facebook SDK 3.5.1 for iOS  Installation Log
Installer[43732]: Opened from: /Volumes/DataHD/myusername/Downloads/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg
Installer[43732]: Product archive /Volumes/DataHD/myusername/Downloads/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg trustLevel=100
Installer[43732]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
Installer[43732]: ================================================================================
Installer[43732]: User picked Standard Install
Installer[43732]: Choices selected for installation:
Installer[43732]:   Install: "Facebook SDK 3.5.1 for iOS"
Installer[43732]:   Install: "Contents"
Installer[43732]:       facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg#package.pkg : com.facebook.sdk.pkg : 0.1
Installer[43732]: ================================================================================
Installer[43732]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Installer[43732]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: location = file://localhost
Installer[43732]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/DataHD/myusername/Downloads/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg#package.pkg
Installer[43732]: Set authorization level to none for session
Installer[43732]: Will use PK session
Installer[43732]: Starting installation:
Installer[43732]: Configuring volume "DataHD"
Installer[43732]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Installer[43732]: Free space on "DataHD": 226.53 GB (226530910208 bytes).
Installer[43732]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/gs/z_zjkd5500v67p65k5ttbs7h0000gn/T//Install.437327ExMnl"
Installer[43732]: IFPKInstallElement (1 packages)
Installer[43732]: Using authorization level of none for IFPKInstallElement
installd[43737]: installd: Starting
installd[43737]: installd: uid=501, euid=501
installd[43737]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
installd[43737]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <1 packages, destination=/Volumes/DataHD/myusername>
installd[43737]: PackageKit: packages=(
        "PKLeopardPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/DataHD/myusername/Downloads/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.1.pkg#package.pkg>"
    )
installd[43737]: PackageKit: Install Failed: (null) (null)
Installer[43732]: Running install actions
Installer[43732]: Removing temporary directory "/var/folders/gs/z_zjkd5500v67p65k5ttbs7h0000gn/T//Install.437327ExMnl"
Installer[43732]: Finalize disk "DataHD"
Installer[43732]: Notifying system of updated components
Installer[43732]: 
Installer[43732]: **** Summary Information ****
Installer[43732]:   Operation      Elapsed time
Installer[43732]: -----------------------------
Installer[43732]:        disk      0.00 seconds
Installer[43732]:      script      0.00 seconds
Installer[43732]:        zero      0.01 seconds
Installer[43732]:     install      1.02 seconds
Installer[43732]:     -total-      1.03 seconds
Installer[43732]: 
Installer[43732]: IFDInstallController DB518730 state = 5
Installer[43732]: Displaying 'Install Succeeded' UI.
```

As you can see, I have 2 disks with my home folder located on the secondary one, `DataHD`. Any ideas?

Comment: installers save all SDK files in the Users directory under documents. try grep FacebookSDK

Comment: No FacebookSDK folder anywhere.

Comment: It turns out installing it via CLI with `CM_BUILD=CM_BUILD` option sort of works: http://hacksoflife.blogspot.ru/2011/08/installer.html

Answer (score 0):

as Shams Ahmed said
check your Document directory.
it should be installed in your document directory.

Comment: No, it's not there. As far as I can see, the problem is that my home folder is on a secondary disk, but I may be wrong. CLI installer sort of works, but installs the SDK into `/Documents`.